# How to check POS printer status

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, escpos

Currently I am working with a POS printer mobile application. I have done text, image and barcode or qrcode printing methods. Now I am trying to retrieve printer status using ESC/POS commands. Below I have attached the code to check the status of print.

```
inStream = btSocket.InputStream;
outStream = btSocket.OutputStream;
                      
byte[] reader = new byte[1024];
                        
//Send command to printer
byte[] @try = "\x10\x04\x01".ToBytes();
outStream.Write(@try, 0, @try.Length);

//Read from printer
if (inStream.CanRead)
{
    //string stat_res = inStream.Read(reader).ToString();
    inStream.Read(reader, 0, reader.Length);
    string text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reader, 0, reader.Length);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Status res: {text}");
}
```

I have tested the code above and i received output as stated below.
In string form it output as an up/down arrow
`[0:] Status res: ?`
or in integer form
`[0:] Status res: 1`

May I know what mistake I did here? I have referred other questions which developed using python or java and converted to C# and it still doesn't produce correct output as I expect. May I know what I did wrong here? I am using ESCPOS Nuget in order to convert text to byte form.

The printer i am using Bixolon and model is SPP-R410. I am developing this application in Xamarin forms using ESC/POS commands.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SPP-R410 Command Manual can be obtained here.
[BIXOLON | Downloads :: mobile printer, portable printer...](https://www.bixolon.com/download_view.php?idx=15#download-anchor05)

According to it, the first 0x10 is unnecessary, only 0x04, 0x01 seems to be good.

Since the status to be notified should be either 0x12:Online or 0x1A:Offline, it is possible that either the correct data has not been notified or your interpretation is incorrect.

Even if the correct data is notified, neither of them is a printable character code, so even if you execute `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` process, you cannot grasp the contents.
In this case, what you should do is `BitConverter.ToString()`.
Alternatively, you can `reader[0].ToString("X")` only the first byte of the reader buffer, since only one byte will be reported.

Comment: I tried to remove 0x10 from the command and the program does not exit from the reading loop. Anyhow, I continued with the same command and executed it and converted the byte to string based on your idea. When I checked the document it shows that 0x00 as Online and 0x08 as Offline. How did you interpreted 0x12 as online and 0x1A as offline? Btw the result was 12 after modifying the code.

Comment: It is described on page 6 of the command manual downloaded from the presented page. Bit4 and Bit1 of the notification data should always be reported as 1, and Bit3 should be reported as 1:Offline,0:Online. By the way, if 12 is notified after the change, it means 0x12 because it is converting byte data to hexadecimal. That would mean online status. The notified byte data value will be the sum of the respective Bit statuses.

Comment: Understood. I was looking the table in wrong way all this time. Thanks for the help.